# How to enable menu link when creating a new node?

Tags: 7, routes

I try to enable the menu link programmatically, here is how I do it:

```
function create_menu_link() {
    $node = new stdClass();
    $node->type = 'mytype';
    node_object_prepare($node);

    $node->menu['link-title'] = $menu_title;

    node_save($node);
}
```

But setting only the title is not working. In `$node->menu` there is some other variables like `mlid` and `plid` which are set to `0` it has to do with this ? The `menu_name` is set to `main-menu:0`, `module` is set to `menu`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to create the menu item separately, using `menu_link_save`

```
$item = array(
  'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
  'link_title' => $node->title,
  'link_path' => 'node/'. $node->nid,
);
menu_link_save($item);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create the link manually. The [menu_node_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!menu!menu.module/function/menu_node_save/7) hook will take care of link creation automatically when saving the node, if you provide the following variables:

```
  $node->menu['enabled'] = TRUE;
  $node->menu['link_title'] = t('My title');
  $node->menu['description'] = ''; // Needed even if empty to avoid notices.
```

Comment: This should have been the correct answer because it use the base principle of Drupal : hook!