# How to put a node in a menu using an URL parameter?

Tags: 7, routes, nodes

While creating a new node, I'd like to pass a parameter in the URL: `node/add/page?plid=123` in order to put the newly created node in this menu item as its child.

I tried to `hook_form_alter()` the node form but I couldn't populate the menu part, also I'd like to hide this part to the end user as they shouldn't alter it.

Should this be done in a `hook_node_insert()` with something like this answer: [How to enable menu link when creating a new node](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/1478/594) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`hook_node_insert()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7) is probably the place to do this. You'll want to call [`menu_link_save()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_link_save/7) to create the menu item, using the `$_GET` superglobal to retrieve the *plid* parameter.

```php
function mymodule_node_insert($node) {
  $item = array(
    'link_path' => 'node/' . $node->nid,
    'link_title' => $node->title,
    'plid' => $_GET['plid'],
  );
  if (!menu_link_save($item)) {
    // It has not been possible to save the menu item.
    // Handle this failure case.
  }
}
```