# Pathauto menu token duplicated for a menu added in hook_node_insert

Tags: 7, hooks, path-aliases, nodes

I have a content type using the following pathauto-token pattern: `[node:menupath]/[node:title]`, I added manually a menu using a hook_node_insert (see my previous question: [creating a menu in a hook_node_insert()](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9301/how-to-put-a-node-in-a-menu-using-an-url-parameter)).

When the node is saved it doesn't have the `[node:menupath]` token in the URL, just the `[node:title]`. I decided to generate the path using pathauto API and this code:

```php
$options = array(
  'language' => isset($node->language) ? $node->language : LANGUAGE_NONE,
);
module_load_include('inc', 'pathauto');
$uri = entity_uri('node', $node);
$path = pathauto_create_alias('node', 'insert', $uri['path'], 
  array('node' => $node), $node->type, $options['language']);
```

Doing this lead to duplicates in the `url_alias` table, the `[node:menupath]/[node:title]` alias being created first then the title.

I tried to add a `$node->pathauto_perform_alias = FALSE;` in a presave, but seems to be inefective.

Also I tried to set my new path in the hook_node_insert but had no success:

```php
$path = pathauto_create_alias('node', 'insert', //...
$node->path = $path;
```

My code doesn't feel right, what would be the normal way to avoid duplicate and getting my pattern to work ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally moved the insertion of my menu in `hook_node_presave()` and then pathauto worked normally.